# Creating a list holding JSON arrays from values in another list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a python script that sends a JSON post. Part of the payload comes from a list in the following format

```
SERVICES = [{'id':'PZV8CL7', 'type':'service'}, {'id':'PYMOSPH', 'type':'service'}]

payload = {
    'maintenance_window': {
        'services': SERVICES,
    }
```

The script works just fine when manually adding the services to the script, however I needed it to be able to work with a lot of them, so I added this:

```
code = ['PH6FKI0', 'PD1EK3Z', 'PSJR02A', 'PI8VRN1']
list = []

for c in code:
    list.append("{'id':'%s', 'type':'service'}" % s) 

print(list)
["{'id':'PH6FKI0', 'type':'service'}", "{'id':'PD1EK3Z', 'type':'service'}"
```

The problem here is that the quotation marks seem to interfere when sent in the the JSON post which returns an error.

```
['Services must be an object containing properties id and type.']
```

How can I make a list without the quotations mark being added to it? any other way to make this, would be awesome as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you generating JSON text, not Python objects (and then using the `json` library to serialize those as/when necessary)?

Comment: Newish at python. Fist time working with JSON

Comment: Gotcha. As a rule -- it's only JSON after it's serialized, or before it's deserialized. Outside those times, your data is just normal Python data, and you shouldn't be treating it differently because it used to be JSON or will be JSON in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert objects, not strings:

```
for c in code:
    list.append({'id':s, 'type':'service'})
```

Comment: Working! Thanks so much! it was the only way I knew how to add something from a list into another thing.